# wso2 password grant how to verify token

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 access Grant for securing a web application.when the user logs in with right credential, I generate the token successful by invoking /oauth2/token service. I store this at the client side and when user invokes the next set of APIs, user hits my API with this token. How can validate the token now ?how can I validate the token to check the scope ? Which serviceI can use for validating the token and user is passing the right token associated with him??

Answer (score 0):

You can use OAuth Introspection Endpoint[1] to validate the token,scope

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Invoke+the+OAuth+Introspection+Endpoint

Comment: is there a rest service which i can use? 
Can it validate the scope associated with the token ..like pass the token and a scope and check if the token has access to scope?

Comment: is there a difference between introspection end point and the wsdl Oauth2TokenValidationService?

Comment: Rest vs SOAP and introspection endpoint is capable to validate the scope

Comment: I tried hitting https://localhost:9443/oauth2/introspect .But i am getting a 404. Any clue?

Comment: how to download 5.3.0. Is it production ready? In the site , the latest version to download is 5.2.0

Comment: it is not released yet . You can use 5.2.0 with oauth2tokenvalidation service https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/OAuth2+Token+Validation

Comment: but does it have a way to validate scope?

Comment: Seems to be there is not way to validate scopes in IS 5.2.0. You have to wait for the 5.3.0 which is scheduled to release soon...